# How to get started with Backbone.js and Rails 3.1

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js

I am trying to learn both Rails and Backbone.js at the same time.
I have completed tutorial here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and now I am trying to get started with Backbone.js.
I planning on using Sprockets for assets packaging but for right now I cant figure out where to put the Backbone.js framework source code itself. I feel like I am missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using [this gem](http://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails) for the integration.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple resources I recommend.

Backbonescreencasts.com has a [screencast on integrating Rails and Backbone.](http://backbonescreencasts.com/backbone-on-rails-basics)

Thoughtbought also has an [ebook on Rails and Backbone](https://workshops.thoughtbot.com/backbone-js-on-rails).

The BackboneFu website has [a page that lists resources](http://backbonefu.com/2011/08/what-are-some-good-resources-for-backbone-js/) for building Backbone apps.